# I have a problem about sleep for loop on ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, sleep

guys i write a chat bot for twitch in hobby.  i want to spam a word in chat in a time like that write to chat"hello" and wait 10 sec then write again 
i did that but in my code have a answer system like that when anyone write to chat !hey my bot answering hello to him. and when i tried in same system that not working

```
until @socket.eof? do 
message = @socket.gets
    puts message
    if message.match(/PRIVMSG ##{@channel} :(.*)$/)
     a = Time.now
     b = Time.now + 5
     while a < b do
      write_to_chat("!prime")
      a += 4
      sleep(20)

     end

     end
       if message.match(/PRIVMSG ##{@channel} :(.*)$/)
      content = $~[1]
      username = message.match(/@(.*).tmi.twitch.tv/)[1]

       if content.include? 'theoSea'

       write_to_chat(" theoAse theoAse theoAse")

       end
```

Comment: sleep works on all codes i want to it just for while loop

Comment: Seeing `$~[1]` is really unusual. Normally you'd use `$1`.

Comment: i tried but nope btw spam is working but answer system not works

Comment: `$1` is the first captured match, or the `(.*)` part in your matching query.

Comment: You're also sleeping 20 seconds in a loop that should run, at most, for 5 seconds but instead runs for 40. You're also adding 4 seconds to `a`, instead of 20? This code is really not making a lot of sense to me.

Comment: Another thing to note is when you call `sleep` here you **suspend all processing of additional messages** until that loop is complete. That's probably not what you want. If this is EventMachine code, consider setting up a proper timer.

Comment: loop works but anyone write to chat theoSea bot dont answer.

Comment: That's because you're jamming the thread with your `sleep` call as I mentioned above. You can't do that.

Comment: look i wrote this code. code working without loop. when i add loop. he doing loop with sleep but this time dont works if codes

Comment: what can i do about that i am newiest on ruby btw

Comment: You'll need to look up how to set a timer.

Comment: ah my brains is dead lol do u have a link for that

Comment: Wrap your `while < a b` block in a `Thread.new do ... end`

Comment: @maxpleaner Depends. In EventMachine there's options and EventMachine hates threads, so...

Comment: i solved it with scheduler btw thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it with scheduler
i wanted a code for write every 5 min i tried lots of method but sleep command 
and i found this link "https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler" 
all in link u can use this gem. 
thx for everything guys.